# setuid sets a large number

Tags: unix, posix, setuid

I have run a program using root in which I called setuid function for uid 9999999 then it successfully sets this uid even it doesn't exist in /etc/passwd. 
SO how setuid validates uid and what will be the impact of setting this invalid uid ?

Answer (score 2):

`setuid` doesn't validate the user ID, only that the process has the privileges to set it.

The system doesn't care if a user doesn't have an entry in `/etc/passwd`; you can, for example, have files owned by any user ID even if there's no "real" user associated with it.

Answer (score 1):

`setuid` typically doesn't validate anything when you have sufficient permissions to perform it (i.e., if you're `root`). It just sets the UID to the one requested, whether or not a username is associated with that UID in `/etc/passwd` or elsewhere.

(According to [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setuid.html), it may fail with `EINVAL` if the UID is invalid, but the Unix flavors that I know never do that.)

Comment: So before setting the uid do we need to validate with /etc/passwd ? what can be impact of setting wrong uids. And what will the behavior of process.

Comment: @sonutiwari: whether you need to validate depends on what you're trying to achieve. The impact is primarily that you create files and start processes that are not owned by any account, but by a numeric UID.